# Can I use any domain name for my active directory domain controller inside a Amazon VPC?

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

In the tutorial I found, it recommended using compute-1.internal as the root suffix and just creating my domain on top of that so I have been using mydomain.compute-1.internal.  I am wondering if I can just setup my domain as mydomain.internal and create a new DHCP option set?

Is there any reason I need to use the compute-1.internal?  If not, how would I setup my DHCP option set?

Comment: `compute-1.internal` would actually be a bad idea, I'd say. Definitely do your own domain. I believe Microsoft recommends real domain names over `.internal` fake TLDs, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Any reasoning on using a real public domain vs a .internal for 100% private network?

Comment: You can't get an SSL certificate for `something.internal` - the CAs won't allow it.

Comment: Why would I need a SSL for my internal network?  All servers are in private subnets.

Comment: Some people want it (and some corporate ITs require it), hence Microsoft advises against it. `internal.company.com`, for example, works fine while still allowing for SSL.

Comment: Why not just follow Microsoft best practice and use a sub-domain of your public domain and end the debate right there?

Comment: @joeqwerty - That is exactly what I am doing... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very short answer: Yes you can.

Slightly longer answer: Do you want split-DNS, or not? (i.e. if you own mydomain.net you can call your active directory domain that as well) or do you want a different name inside (i.e. mydomain.local + mydomain.net externally)

Comment: There will be lots of different websites on the servers.  This is all for internal use.  Not sure about any advantage to using a public domain name for the internal services.

Comment: It won't make any difference then really.  You can use 'fake' authoritative DNS zones and listen for various headers in IIS (or whatever web server you are using) for the different websites.  As for SSL, if this is all development / non-production, you _could_ make your own CA and trust your own certificates using group policy settings - but all this is getting away from the original question.